# Display quantity as like price textfield

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, controllers, edit

we are using following code for updating price

```
<td>

<input onFocus="showPriceCancel('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>');" class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>

<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />

<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>


<button style="display:none;" id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>

</span>

</td>


<script>

function hideResetPrice(product_id,priceold) { 

var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id; 

$wk_jq(resetButton).hide(); 
$wk_jq(valueprice).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currprice).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}


function updateFieldPrice(product_id) 
{ 
var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>'; 
$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currprice).val($price); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}


</script>

<?php

// controller.php

public function updateFieldPriceAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        

        $product->setPrice($upd_price);


        $product->save();

        echo $price = $product->getPrice();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

it looks like this : [image]

we are using following code for quantity :

```
<td>
<?php
$selllermpassignproduct=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($products->getId());
//Zend_Debug::dump($selllermpassignproduct,null,true);
$stock_item=Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products);

$SellerQty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['sellerqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['sellerqty']:$stock_item->getQty();
$assignqty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['assignqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['assignqty']:0;
?>

<span id="valueqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo (int) $SellerQty; ?></span>


<input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name = "stock" value = "<?php echo (int) $SellerQty; ?>" style = "display:none"/>



<span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
<img onclick="showField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
</span>  

<p id="updatedqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p>
<br/>


<button id="update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="buttons" onclick="updateField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>',<?php echo $assignqty;?>); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>

<button id="reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideReset('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>



<script>

function hideReset(product_id) {

            var qtyId='#qty_'+ product_id;
            var editLink="#edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).hide();
            $wk_jq(editLink).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).hide();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).hide();
        }





         function showField(product_id)
        {

            var qtyId='#qty_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }



             function updateField(product_id,assignqty)
        {
            var qtyId = '#qty_'+ product_id;
            var valueId = '#valueqty_'+ product_id;
            var updatedqty = '#updatedqty_'+ product_id;


            var editLink = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton = "#reset_button"+ product_id;
            var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateField/')?>';

            $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle()

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();
            jQuery(valueId).html($qty);
            hideReset(product_id);

            var tmpQty=assignqty+ parseInt($qty) ;

            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                method: 'post',
                parameters: {id: product_id, qty: tmpQty},
                onComplete: function (transport) {
                    //alert(transport.responseText);
                    jQuery(priceId).val($price);
            // $wk_jq(priceId).setValue($price);

                    jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();

                    $updateButton.prop('disabled', false);

                    // $wk_jq(qtyId).setValue($qty);



                }
            });
        }

public function updateFieldAction(){
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
        $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));

        $stockItem->save();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));
      }
```

its displaying like this : [image]

means once we click on edit button, its displaying like this.

I want to display quantity as like price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add class `ama1` input and remove `display:none`

```
<span id="valueqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php //echo (int) $SellerQty; ?></span>
<input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name = "stock" class="ama1" value = "<?php echo (int) $SellerQty; ?>" />



<span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
<!-- <img onclick="showField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/> -->
</span>  

<p id="updatedqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p>
<br/>


<button id="update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="buttons" onclick="updateField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>',<?php echo $assignqty;?>); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>

<button id="reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideReset('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;"  >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
```